# p5.js Shape Adjustments Leaving Previous Outlines Visible

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to simply adjust the shape of an object using a value derived from a slider on a screen using p5.js.

The issue I am having is that the outline of the previously drawn shapes remain, giving an after-trail effect.

I have tried the `noStroke()` modifier but that simply does not draw the shape. As well the `noFill()` gives an even weirder, yet still incorrect, behavoir.

Code Example: https://codepen.io/galleywest/pen/oejxyY

```
var slider

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600)
  slider = createSlider(0, 50, 0)
}

function draw() {
  rect(10, 10, 80, 80, slider.value())
}
```

How can I mitigate this behavior?

Comment: When I run your CodePen I just see a blank white square without a slider.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `background()` function to clear out old frames.

```
var slider

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600)
  slider = createSlider(0, 50, 0)
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 0, 0); //draws a red background
  rect(10, 10, 80, 80, slider.value())
}
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background).

Comment: This is the answer. It says I need three more minutes to accept the answer. I will do that then.